# Change year format in momentjs to Buddhist era

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I want to show date/time in B.E.(Buddhist era) format, such as 2015 -> 2558

```
moment().format('D MMMM YYYY  H:mm:ss')
```

Any Idea?

Comment: what is B.E format? any example?

Comment: I'm sorry for my eng. Ex. 2015 -> 2558 (Buddhist era)

Comment: If i understand correctly, your solution can be as simple as get the year now, add 543 years to it, and display that.

Answer (score 7):

```
 date.toLocaleDateString('th-TH', { day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric' });
```

Have you ever try this.

Ps. This one is not moment.js but vanila js.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is doable since Moment doesn't have pluggable calendar system required for alternative calendars to work.

[At least the *Open* status of this GitHub issue suggests so.](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1454)

The issue states:

> **Non-Gregorian calendars inside moment.js**
>
> On MediaWiki, date formatter easily can generate non-Gregorian
>   calendars output.
>
> This is a copy of the related parts of [MediaWiki documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions#.23time).

The linked MediaWiki article includes a table of date and time formatters including `xkY` for [Thai solar calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_solar_calendar).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10313710)

Comment: Thanks, @PCLuddite, I've included a direct quote from the issue and some additional links.